# Округление в большую сторону не работает

Tags: java, math

```
int a = 28;
int b = (int) Math.ceil(a * 200 / 900);
sout(b)
```

Выдает 6. Ожидаю 7.

Обычный калькулятор даёт 28 * 200 / 900 = 6.2222, и я ожидаю в 
этом коде округления в большую сторону.

Что не так делаю?

Comment: А почему вы ожидаете 7?

Comment: Потому что целочисленное деление

Comment: Какой это язык?

Comment: Это я зык Java.

Comment: 7 ожидаю, т.к. на калькуляторе выдает 28*200/900=6.2222. Если math.ceil округляет в большую, то жду 7.

Comment: если делать double, то выдает 6.0. Я вообще не понимаю что происходит..
double b = Math.ceil(a * 200 / 900) // = 6.0 :(

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540684/java-round-up-any-number

Comment: Nikita Kazantsev, спасибо. Получилось. Если тут можно как-то лайки ставить, я готов, только подскажите как.:)

Comment: @NikitaKazantsev ответы в ответ.

Answer (score 3):

У вас все операции целочисленные, так что все правильно

```
28*200/900=5600/900=6
```

Надо делать так:

```
28*200.0/900=5600.0/900=6.2222
Math.ceil(6.2222)=7.0
```